# Issue Getting nanoFramework to Deploy and Run on ESP32D02DQ66

Tags: .net, esp32, visual-studio-2022, nanoframework

Having issues deploying “Hello World” to ESP32_WROOM_32 device. I was able to flash the device successfully using nonoff. I have a ESP32D0WDQ6 and flashed ESP32_WROOM_32 v1.0.7.2 to it. I am using .NET nanoFramework Extension v2022.2.0.8 and VS version 17.1.3. I am also using nanoFramework.CoreLibrary v1.10.5. Below is from Device capabilities:

```
System Information
HAL build info: nanoFramework running @ ESP32
  Target:   ESP32_WROOM_32
  Platform: ESP32

Firmware build Info:
  Date:        Aug 25 2021
  Type:        MinSizeRel build with IDF v3.3.5
  CLR Version: 1.7.0.618
  Compiler:    GNU ARM GCC v5.2.0

OEM Product codes (vendor, model, SKU): 0, 0, 0

Serial Numbers (module, system):
  00000000000000000000000000000000
  0000000000000000

Target capabilities:
  Has nanoBooter: NO
  IFU capable: NO
  Has proprietary bootloader: YES
```

AppDomains:

Assemblies:

Native Assemblies:

```
 mscorlib v100.5.0.12, checksum 0x132BDB6F

  nanoFramework.Runtime.Native v100.0.8.0, checksum 0x2307A8F3

  nanoFramework.Hardware.Esp32 v100.0.7.2, checksum 0x1B75B894

  nanoFramework.Hardware.Esp32.Rmt v100.0.3.0, checksum 0x9A53BB44

  nanoFramework.Devices.OneWire v100.0.3.4, checksum 0xA5C172BD

  nanoFramework.Networking.Sntp v100.0.4.4, checksum 0xE2D9BDED

  nanoFramework.ResourceManager v100.0.0.1, checksum 0xDCD7DF4D

  nanoFramework.System.Collections v100.0.0.1, checksum 0x5A31313D

  nanoFramework.System.Text v100.0.0.1, checksum 0x8E6EB73D

  nanoFramework.Runtime.Events v100.0.8.0, checksum 0x0EAB00C9

  EventSink v1.0.0.0, checksum 0xF32F4C3E

  System.IO.FileSystem v1.0.0.0, checksum 0x3112D24C

  System.Math v100.0.5.2, checksum 0xC9E0AB13

  System.Net v100.1.3.4, checksum 0xC74796C2

  Windows.Devices.Adc v100.1.3.3, checksum 0xCA03579A

  System.Device.Dac v100.0.0.6, checksum 0x02B3E860

  System.Device.Gpio v100.1.0.4, checksum 0xB6D0ACC1

  Windows.Devices.Gpio v100.1.2.2, checksum 0xC41539BE

  Windows.Devices.I2c v100.2.0.2, checksum 0x79EDBF71

  System.Device.I2c v100.0.0.1, checksum 0xFA806D33

  Windows.Devices.Pwm v100.1.3.3, checksum 0xBA2E2251

  Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication v100.1.1.2, checksum 0x34BAF06E

  System.IO.Ports v100.1.1.3, checksum 0x61B8380C

  Windows.Devices.Spi v100.1.4.2, checksum 0x360239F1

  System.Device.Spi v100.1.0.0, checksum 0x48031DC5

  Windows.Devices.Wifi v100.0.6.2, checksum 0xA94A849E

  Windows.Storage v100.0.2.0, checksum 0x954A4192



++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++        Memory Map          ++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  Type     Start       Size
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  RAM   0x3ffe436c  0x00016800
  FLASH 0x00000000  0x00400000



+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++                   Flash Sector Map                        ++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  Region     Start      Blocks   Bytes/Block    Usage
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      0    0x00010000       1      0x180000     nanoCLR
      1    0x00190000       1      0x230000     Deployment
      2    0x003C0000       1      0x040000     Configuration


+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++              Storage Usage Map                ++
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  Start        Size (kB)           Usage
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  0x003C0000    0x040000 (256kB)    Configuration
  0x00010000    0x180000 (1536kB)   nanoCLR
  0x00190000    0x230000 (2240kB)   Deployment
```

Deployment Map
Empty

When deploying “Hello World” template it appears as though debugger is started on device and assemblies are uploaded ok. Then when VS launches the debugger provider I get the following error:

[image]

```
08:31:24.428 [Starting deployment transaction from v2022.2.0+f1998f9dd6]

08:31:24.432 [Starting debug engine on nanoDevice]

08:31:24.442 [Connecting to debugger engine...OK]

08:31:27.208 [Assemblies to deploy:]

08:31:27.208 [Assembly: NFApp4 v1.0.0.0 (336 bytes)]

08:31:27.223 [Assembly: mscorlib v1.10.5.4 (31668 bytes)]

08:31:27.224 [Deploying 2 assemblies to device]

08:31:27.913 [Incrementally deploying assemblies to the device]

08:31:27.932 [Erasing block @ 0x00190000...]

08:31:28.330 [Deploying 0/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.355 [Deploying 1012/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.380 [Deploying 2024/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.405 [Deploying 3036/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.439 [Deploying 4048/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.455 [Deploying 5060/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.481 [Deploying 6072/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.505 [Deploying 7084/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.540 [Deploying 8096/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.558 [Deploying 9108/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.584 [Deploying 10120/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.613 [Deploying 11132/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.644 [Deploying 12144/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.681 [Deploying 13156/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.686 [Deploying 14168/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.713 [Deploying 15180/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.736 [Deploying 16192/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.761 [Deploying 17204/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.788 [Deploying 18216/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.813 [Deploying 19228/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.836 [Deploying 20240/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.866 [Deploying 21252/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.887 [Deploying 22264/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.913 [Deploying 23276/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.946 [Deploying 24288/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.965 [Deploying 25300/32004 bytes.]

08:31:28.994 [Deploying 26312/32004 bytes.]

08:31:29.021 [Deploying 27324/32004 bytes.]

08:31:29.055 [Deploying 28336/32004 bytes.]

08:31:29.068 [Deploying 29348/32004 bytes.]

08:31:29.095 [Deploying 30360/32004 bytes.]

08:31:29.121 [Deploying 31372/32004 bytes.]

08:31:29.154 [Assemblies successfully deployed to the device]

08:31:29.193 [Launching debugger provider from v2022.2.0+f1998f9dd6]
```

At this point the COM port becomes locked and no more communication on that COM port will occur. I can unplug and plug the ESP32 but the device will not enumerate. The only way I can fix the issue is by rebooting my PC. Can someone please point me in the direction on what to check next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESP32_WROOM_32 target has been deprecated. You should have seen a message about this from nanoff.
Having said that, please use one of the current targets and you should be good to go.

`nanoff --update --serialport COM9999 --platform esp32`